# .net, treeview, nodes, custom properties

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a treeview to display some DB hierarchically data, by populating with recursion.
I use node.name property as unique object ID from DB (the key) and node.text for objects friendly name.

Now since I already use some queries to populate the TV, would be nice to store some other objects properties that I may need in app but 'nodes' haven't any custom properties, except node.tag which I already use.

The question is can I have something like custom nodes (with custom properties) and still can be linked to treeview?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use the `Tag` property to store a structure/List/Dictionary of properties.

Example :

```
        Dim NodeProperties As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        NodeProperties.Add("Property1", "value1")
        NodeProperties.Add("Property2", "value2")

        node.Tag = NodeProperties
```

Comment: Ooopps... I miss that, tag is object :) of course.thanks a lot